# Accessing Variables Used In a Plugin Using PHPStorm + XDebug

Tags: php, plugin-development, debug

I'm currently attempting to use XDebug 2.2.1 and PHPStorm 7.1 to debug my WordPress plugin. So far, I've successfully installed XDebug and breakpoints are working fine. However, I'm unable to access any of the variables being used in the functions in which I'm breaking.

For instance, I break in this code:

```
function generateGoalCard($sub) {
        $goalID = $this->CodeLibrary->convertStringToInt($sub->goalID);
        $userID = $this->CodeLibrary->convertStringToInt($sub->userID);
        print('goalID: '); // BREAK POINT HERE
        // Other unimportant code ...
}
```

Below is a screenshot of the debugging window at the above break point. As you can see, `$goalID` and `$userID` are not accessible. How can I gain access to my plugin's variables?

[image]

[Here's the screenshot in DropBox.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pzvt6mi4rlcwsdl/Screenshot%202014-06-04%2009.25.33.png)

Comment: Can you evaluate what the values are using the debug Terminal when paused at that breakpoint?

Comment: @hereswhatidid: No, I'm not. In the "Evaluate Expression" window, inputting `$goalID` returns `result = null`.

Comment: I just tried putting the break point a few lines further down in the code so I could see a `var_dump` I was doing of `$userID` and then opened my page in a new tab. Again, PHPStorm catches the breakpoint but nothing is rendered in the page. I'm not knowledgable enough to know whether or not that `var_dump` should have been rendered in my browser before the code execution was suspended. After resuming the code, the `var_dump` is rendered as expected.

Comment: Note, too, that I'm using the zero-configuration debugging approach with Chrome bookmarklets, and that the file I'm breaking in is not named `index.php` like the Frames pane seems to believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current understanding is that the problem was caused by the fact that my project only encompassed a plugin directory while the page I was debugging was generated by many php files outside the project directory.

The fix took just two changes to PHPStorm preferences:

1. Go to `PHPStorm > Preferences > Project Settings > PHP > Debug` and disable `Force break at the first line when no path mapping specified`.
2. Go to `PHPStorm > Preferences > Project Settings > PHP > Servers` and disable `Use path mappings (select if the server is remote or symlinks are used`.

With those two changes, it all seems to be working perfectly fine.

Comment: Dear @LeoFNaN: Thanks for the edit, but I'm on a Mac, not Windows. Reverting...